# Changing text on back button in dashcode. Where do I put this code?

Tags: javascript, text, back-button, dashcode

This is probably a very simple question, but I'm working with dashcode and can't figure out where to put this code to change the text of the back button.

```
 self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem =
      [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"
               style: UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
               target:nil
               action:nil] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 2):

Dashcode is the development tool that Apple has provided for web based development (Javascript/HTML/CSS).

The code you have pasted is Objective-C code which is used in native development with XCode.

So, either you have the wrong tool, or are using the wrong language. HTH.